# Can I specify factor levels as the sorted variable of another data set?

Tags: r

I am trying to visualize the tendency of students from different high school programmes to drop out of their university studies. I have managed to get a very good visualization on their in-group percentage to stay in the programme, drop out late or drop out early.

I write:

```
fulldata %>%
as_tibble() %>%
group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal))%>% 
ggplot(.) + 
geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
coord_flip() + 
facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

And I get:

[image]

That's really great but for completeness' sake I'd like to sort the groups depending on decending values in the first facet. I can of course define "gymnasiegrov" as a factor and reorder the factor levels manually, but this is the first of "many" analyses and that would quickly become tedious.

I have tried to create a table, sort it depending on relative frequency and then use the sorted vector as the factor levels in my first data set. This procedure could then be repeated for each new population. Unfortunatly this doesn't seem to work:

```
#creating table#

vettig_tabell<-table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,fulldata$totstatus_tri)
vettig_tabell<-as.data.frame(vettig_tabell)
vettig_tabell<-spread(vettig_tabell, Var2, Freq)
vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%mutate(ongoing=`pågående studier`/(`pågående studier` + `tidigt avbrott eller återbud` + `troligt avbrott`))

#sorting by relative frequency#

vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%arrange(ongoing)

#Trying to use order of programmes sorted on relative frequency as factor levels#

fulldata$gymnasiegrov<-factor(fulldata$gymnasiegrov, levels=vettig_tabell$Var2, ordered=TRUE)
```

......For some reason this turns every single one of my values into NA.

Any ideas?

Snapshot of data (relevant variables only)

```
structure(list(gymnasiegrov = c("Hotell- och Restaurang", NA, 
"specialutformat program", "komvux", NA, "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "komvux", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
NA, "specialutformat program", "estetiska programmet", "medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", "komvux", 
"estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "specialutformat program", 
"friskoleprogram", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"teknikprogrammet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"komvux", "specialutformat program", "specialutformat program", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "komvux", 
"Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "friskoleprogram", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "specialutformat program", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "komvux", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"estetiska programmet", "estetiska programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "estetiska programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "naturvetenskapliga programmet", 
"teknikprogrammet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "estetiska programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "teknikprogrammet", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), totstatus_bin = c("troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "troligt avbrott eller återbud", 
"pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"troligt avbrott eller återbud", "pågående studier", "pågående studier", 
"pågående studier")), row.names = c(NA, -162L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works when i write "Var1" instead of "Var2" so I apologize for stupid question.

I thus submit the following:

```
#creating table#

vettig_tabell<-table(fulldata$gymnasiegrov,fulldata$totstatus_tri)
vettig_tabell<-as.data.frame(vettig_tabell)
vettig_tabell<-spread(vettig_tabell, Var2, Freq)
vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%mutate(ongoing=`pågående studier`/(`pågående studier` + `tidigt avbrott eller återbud` + `troligt avbrott`))

#sorting by relative frequency#

vettig_tabell<-vettig_tabell%>%arrange(ongoing)

#Trying to use order of programmes sorted on relative frequency as factor levels#

fulldata$gymnasiegrov<-factor(fulldata$gymnasiegrov, levels=vettig_tabell$Var1, ordered=TRUE)

fulldata %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    group_by(gymnasiegrov, totstatus_tri) %>% 
    summarise(antal = n()) %>% 
    mutate(andel = antal / sum(antal))%>% 
    ggplot(.) + 
    geom_col(mapping = aes(x = gymnasiegrov, y = andel)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(~totstatus_tri)
```

And get the following output in return:

[image]